# Is this a Hurwitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, hurwitz-matrices

I have the following block matrix

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C &D\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A, B, C, D$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices and

1.$A$ is Hurwitz and $a_{ii} < 0$

2. $B = \operatorname{diag}(b_1, b_2)$ with $b_i < 0$.
3. $C = \operatorname{diag}(c_1, c_2)$ with $c_i> 0$.
4. $D = \operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2)$ with $d_i < 0$.

Is there some necessary and/or sufficient condition on $B, C, D$ for J to be Hurwitz?

Comment: search for Schur complement formula

Comment: Hurwitz matrix means different things in different contexts. You may want to state your definition in your question.

Comment: @user1551 In this context, a square matrix A is called stable matrix (or sometimes Hurwitz matrix) if every eigenvalue of A has strictly negative real part. Thank you very much!

Comment: @percusse Please, explain your answer in more detail. Thank you very much.